# Error importing stdlib.h from Swift Bridging Header (Linux)

Tags: c, swift, linux, bridging-header

I have installed Swift 4.1.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 using [these instructions](https://swift.org/download/#releases). Normal Swift-only code works perfectly, but I need to interface with some C libraries so I've included a bridging header. However, whenever the bridging header (or any of its dependencies) contains the line:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

I get the following error when compiling:

```
<unknown>:0: error: module 'SwiftGlibc' in AST file '/tmp/org.llvm.clang.ubuntu/ModuleCache/7NOV3A4XDTWQ/SwiftGlibc-1JWOQWYGL30RZ.pcm' (imported by AST file '/tmp/test-31a824.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/home/ubuntu/swift-4.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/glibc.modulemap'?
<unknown>:0: note: consider adding '/home/ubuntu/swift-4.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64' to the header search path
<unknown>:0: note: imported by '/tmp/test-31a824.pch'
<unknown>:0: error: clang importer creation failed
```

I've tried to follow the instructions by `/home/ubuntu/swift-4.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64` to my `$CPATH`, but I haven't been able to fix this error. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `$CPATH` controls C include directories, but the file the compiler is looking for is a `.modulemap`; have you tried `swiftc -I /home/ubuntu/swift-4.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64`?

Comment: Additionally, if the only reason you need a bridging header with stdlib.h is to access glibc functions, you can write `import Glibc` in your Swift code.

Comment: No luck with the `-I` flag. I need to `#include <stdlib.h>` because the header file of the C library I want to include uses it.

Comment: Does “@import Glibc;” instead of the include statement work? It’s the Objective-C syntax for module imports.

Comment: No, that causes a syntax error: `error: expected identifier or '('`